# iPad MPMoviePlayerController iOS 5.1 issue in UISplitView

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm new to iOS and finished my 2nd project I built with a `SplitView` in storyboards. I built this, in iOS 5 and now seeing in 5.1 that in portrait view my popover is now a slider. I read up on the Apple notes for 5.1 and decided to just let the `tableview` stay as a slider. I have an array of movies that fire on row select that go to fullscreen when selected. In landscape when the master view is visible, things work ok as expected. On `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the video fires and goes to fullscreen, on portrait mode (my popover is now a slider) that on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the video does not fire off fullscreen, it actually plays in the master view, and my detail view content stays in view. What am I missing here? this is the code I have in the table view (noLandscape is a subclass of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VideoInfo *videoInfo =(VideoInfo*) [listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoInfo.strFileName]; 

    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    MoviePlayerViewCtrler = [[noLandscape alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:MoviePlayerViewCtrler];


    [MoviePlayerViewCtrler.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:MoviePlayerViewCtrler];
    [MoviePlayerViewCtrler.moviePlayer play];

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to play the movie in your detailviewcontroller and not the masterviewcontroller.  So in your detailviewcontroller needs to be messaged by which row is selected in the masterviewcontroller.  Then load the appropriate movie in the detail view, and then pop your modal view to display the movie.